Lost in the forest - Aligning Nodes Vertically for 4th-Level Nodes
I'm trying to create a hierarchical structure using the forest package (I am realy not familiar with, but learning).
I'm encountering some issues with the layout at deeper levels. Specifically, I want the nodes at the 4th level to be aligned vertically, one above the other, rather than side by side... (and any other advice to improve this far too large forest).

Here’s my code :
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath} % For text in math mode
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tikzset{every shadow/.style={shadow xshift=5pt,shadow yshift=-5pt}}

\forestset{
    commonNodeStyle/.style={
        font=\sffamily,
        line width=1pt,
        draw,
        align=center,
    },
    NodeT/.style={
        commonNodeStyle,
        fill=blue!15,
        text width=6cm,
        minimum height=1.2cm,
        font=\large\bfseries,
    },
    NodeS/.style={
        commonNodeStyle,
        fill=orange!20,
        text width=5.5cm,
        minimum height=1cm,
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        font=\sffamily,
        line width=1pt,
        draw,
        child anchor=north,
        parent anchor=south,
        grow=south,
        align=center,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[line width=1pt, \forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.parent anchor) |- ([yshift=4pt].child anchor) -- (.child anchor) \forestoption{edge label};
        },
        s sep+=10pt, 
        l sep+=20pt, 
        for level=4{ % Special settings for level 4 nodes that don't work :/
            s sep=0pt, 
            l sep+=10pt, 
        },
    },
    [ {Exotic Options}, NodeT
        [ {Vanilla Options}, NodeT
            [ {Standard European Call/Put}, NodeS
                [ {Payoff : \( C = \max(S_T - K, 0) \)}, NodeS]
                [ {Payoff : \( P = \max(K - S_T, 0) \)}, NodeS]
            ]
        ]
        [ {American Options}, NodeT
            [ {Peuvent être exercées à tout moment avant l’échéance}, NodeS
                [ {Payoff : \( C_A = \max(S_t - K, 0) \)}, NodeS]
                [ {Payoff : \( P_A = \max(K - S_t, 0) \)}, NodeS]
            ]
        ]
        [ {Asian Options}, NodeT
            [ {Average Price Option}, NodeS
                [ {Call : \( C = \max\left(\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T S_t \, dt - K, 0\right) \)}, NodeS]
                [ {Put : \( P = \max\left(K - \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T S_t \, dt, 0\right) \)}, NodeS]
                [ {Définition : \( S_{\text{ave}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} S_i \)}, NodeS]
            ]
            [ {Average Strike Option}, NodeS
                [ {Call : \( C = \max\left(S_T - \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T S_t \, dt, 0\right) \)}, NodeS]
                [ {Put : \( P = \max\left(\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T S_t \, dt - S_T, 0\right) \)}, NodeS]
            ]
        ]
        [ {Barrier Options}, NodeT
            [ {Knock-in}, NodeS
                [ {Active seulement si la barrière \(B\) est franchie}, NodeS]
                [ {Call/Put : \( C_{ki} \) ou \( P_{ki} \)}, NodeS]
            ]
            [ {Knock-out}, NodeS
                [ {Invalide si la barrière \(B\) est franchie}, NodeS]
                [ {Call/Put : \( C_{ko} \) ou \( P_{ko} \)}, NodeS]
            ]
            [ {Double Barrier}, NodeS
                [ {Active seulement si le prix reste entre \(B_{\text{low}}\) et \(B_{\text{high}}\)}, NodeS]
            ]
        ]
        [ {Lookback Options}, NodeT
            [ {Floating Lookback}, NodeS
                [ {Call : \( C = \max(S_T - S_{\min}, 0) \)}, NodeS]
                [ {Put : \( P = \max(S_{\max} - S_T, 0) \)}, NodeS]
                [ {Définitions : \( S_{\min} = \min(S_0, \ldots, S_T) \), \( S_{\max} = \max(S_0, \ldots, S_T) \)}, NodeS]
            ]
            [ {Fixed Lookback}, NodeS
                [ {Call : \( C = \max(S_{\max} - K, 0) \)}, NodeS]
                [ {Put : \( P = \max(K - S_{\min}, 0) \)}, NodeS]
            ]
        ]
        [ {Digital/Binary Options}, NodeT
            [ {Cash-or-Nothing}, NodeS
                [ {Paie un montant fixe \(Q\) si \(S_T > K\)}, NodeS]
                [ {Payoff : \( Q \cdot 1_{S_T > K} \)}, NodeS]
            ]
            [ {Asset-or-Nothing}, NodeS
                [ {Paie le prix de l'actif si \(S_T > K\)}, NodeS]
                [ {Payoff : \( S_T \cdot 1_{S_T > K} \)}, NodeS]
            ]
        ]
        [ {Compound Options}, NodeT
            [ {Call on Call}, NodeS
                [ {Donne le droit d'acheter une autre option call}, NodeS]
            ]
            [ {Put on Call}, NodeS
                [ {Donne le droit de vendre une option call}, NodeS]
            ]
        ]
        [ {Chooser Options}, NodeT
            [ {Permet de choisir entre un call ou un put à une date future}, NodeS]
            [ {Payoff : \( \max(S_T - K, K - S_T) \)}, NodeS]
        ]
        [ {Cliquet Options}, NodeT
            [ {Série d’options qui se réinitialisent périodiquement en fonction des performances}, NodeS]
            [ {Courantes dans les produits actions à long terme}, NodeS]
        ]
        [ {Forward Start Options}, NodeT
            [ {Option dont le prix d’exercice est déterminé à une date future \(T_1\)}, NodeS]
            [ {Exemple : Option de stock pour employés}, NodeS]
            [ {Call : \( C = e^{-r(T_2 - T_1)} \cdot (S_{T_1} - K_{T_1})^+ \)}, NodeS]
        ]
        [ {Basket Options}, NodeT
            [ {Options basées sur un portefeuille d’actifs}, NodeS]
            [ {Le payoff peut dépendre de la moyenne, du minimum ou du maximum des prix du panier}, NodeS]
            [ {Exemple : Basket Call : \( C = e^{-rT} \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i S_i - K\right)^+ \)}, NodeS]
        ]
        [ {Ladder Options}, NodeT
            [ {Verrouille les gains au fur et à mesure que le prix de l’actif atteint de nouveaux niveaux}, NodeS]
            [ {Payoff : \( \max(S_T - K_i, 0) \), où \(K_i\) sont les échelons}, NodeS]
        ]
        [ {Gap Options}, NodeT
            [ {Le payoff dépend de deux prix d’exercice : \(K_1\) (strike) et \(K_2\) (trigger)}, NodeS]
            [ {Call : \( C = 1_{S_T > K_2} \cdot (S_T - K_1) \)}, NodeS]
            [ {Put : \( P = 1_{S_T < K_2} \cdot (K_1 - S_T) \)}, NodeS]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}



I can give you the structure of the tree, but the result will still be far too wide for any ordinary page. to avoid that, you need to rethink the way you present some or all of the content. if the text was english, I might try to suggest something (though such things are notoriously sensitive to discipline), but I can't do that for french. you could reduce some content by taking out repeated words e.g. represent 'Payoff' in some shorthand way (a different colour or a symbol or something). but if you put very long things into boxes and line them up, you kind of have to get an even longer thing.

This is not a solution. It is intended to illustrate some of the things you could do:

utilise symbols for repeated words such as 'Payoff'
line breaks within nodes
smaller font sizes
vertical stacking of nodes e.g. leaves.

You could also move some of the nodes down. However, I think it would be much, much better to rethink the way you present whatever this is supposed to be communicating. When your tree is over 2 metres wide, you have to recognise that a rethink is required.
If you use a tree at all, the contents of nodes need to be short. Do not try to include sentences. Do not try to include everything.

What is most important about the diagram?
What two or three points do you want to ensure the reader takes from it?
Or what single point do you want to ensure the viewer takes from it if this is a presentation?

If you need more detail, that goes in the text or in tables or whatever. A diagram is not intended to be standalone.

Is a tree the best way to convey the information?
Would, say, a payoff matrix or series of such matrices be more effective?
Would a flow chart work better? Or a chart of some kind?

For whatever it is worth, here's the tree in a version which is less than 2 metres wide, but still entirely absurd.
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729664/
% addaswyd o gwestiwn JeT: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/729654/
\usepackage{amsmath} % For text in math mode
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{array}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/720963/
\forestset{%
  calign/middle edge or midpoint/.style={%
    if={>Ow+P{n children}{isodd(##1)}}{%
      calign'=child edge,
      calign primary child/.process={Ow+x{n children}{\inteval{(##1+1)/2}}},%{##1/2}},
    }{calign'=midpoint},
  },
  declare boolean={switcheroo}{0},
  folders down 2/.style={%
    delay={%
      where switcheroo={%
        prepend={
          [,
          % no edge,
          coordinate,
          calign with current,
          grow'=0,
          delay={%
            while nodewalk valid={n}{append=!n,do dynamics},
          },
          before typesetting nodes={
            calign primary child=1,
            calign=child edge,
            for descendants={%
              folder,
              fork sep'=0pt,
            },
          },
          before computing xy={%
            % l'=5pt,
            for descendants={%
              % s'-=\baselineskip,
              l'=1.5em,
            }
          }
          ]
        },
      }{},
    }
  },
  commonNodeStyle/.style={
    font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
    line width=1pt,
    draw,
    align=center,
  },
  NodeT/.style={
    commonNodeStyle,
    fill=blue!15,
    % text width=6cm,
    minimum height=1.2cm,
    font=\bfseries\sffamily,
  },
  NodeS/.style={
    commonNodeStyle,
    fill=orange!20,
    % text width=55mm,
    minimum height=1cm,
  },
  payoff/.style={%
    delay={%
      +content=\textdagger,
    },
  },
  call/.style={%
    delay={%
      +content=\textdaggerdbl,
    },
  },
  put/.style={%
    delay={%
      +content=\textsuperscript{*},
    },
  },
}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  folders down 2,% enable a switch to folder style
  % calign=middle edge or midpoint,
  for leaves={% actually say were we want the switch to happen
    !u.switcheroo,% in the parents of terminal nodes
    delay={align=@{}l@{}},
  },
  where level>=2{NodeS}{NodeT},
  for tree={
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  before packing={%
    where={ >OOw2+d_> O_=! &  {max x}{min x}{#1-#2}{30mm} {n children}{0}  }
    {align=C{30mm},typeset node}{},
  },
  [ {Exotic Options}
    [ {Vanilla Options}
      [ {Standard European Call/Put}
        [ {\( C = \max(S_T - K, 0) \)},payoff]
        [ {\( P = \max(K - S_T, 0) \)},payoff]
      ]
    ]
    [ {American Options}
      [ {Peuvent être exercées à tout moment avant l’échéance}
        [ {\( C_A = \max(S_t - K, 0) \)},payoff]
        [ {\( P_A = \max(K - S_t, 0) \)},payoff]
      ]
    ]
    [ {Asian Options}
      [ {Average Price Option}
        [ {\( C = \max\left(\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T S_t \, dt - K, 0\right) \)},call]
        [ {\( P = \max\left(K - \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T S_t \, dt, 0\right) \)},put]
        [ {Définition :\\\( S_{\text{ave}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} S_i \)}]
      ]
      [ {Average Strike Option}
        [ {\( C = \max\left(S_T - \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T S_t \, dt, 0\right) \)},call]
        [ {\( P = \max\left(\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T S_t \, dt - S_T, 0\right) \)},put]
      ]
    ]
    [ {Barrier Options}
      [ {Knock-in}
        [ {Active seulement\\si la barrière\\\(B\) est franchie}]
        [ {\( C_{ki} \) ou \( P_{ki} \)},call,put]
      ]
      [ {Knock-out}
        [ {Invalide si la barrière\\\(B\) est franchie}]
        [ {\( C_{ko} \) ou \( P_{ko} \)},call,put]
      ]
      [ {Double Barrier}
        [ {Active seulement si\\le prix reste entre\\\(B_{\text{low}}\) et \(B_{\text{high}}\)}]
      ]
    ]
    [ {Lookback Options}
      [ {Floating Lookback}
        [ {\( C = \max(S_T - S_{\min}, 0) \)},call]
        [ {\( P = \max(S_{\max} - S_T, 0) \)},put]
        [ {Définitions : \( S_{\min} = \min(S_0, \ldots, S_T) \), \( S_{\max} = \max(S_0, \ldots, S_T) \)}]
      ]
      [ {Fixed Lookback}
        [ {\( C = \max(S_{\max} - K, 0) \)},call]
        [ {\( P = \max(K - S_{\min}, 0) \)},put]
      ]
    ]
    [ {Digital/Binary Options}
      [ {Cash-or-Nothing}
        [ {Paie un montant fixe \(Q\) si \(S_T > K\)}]
        [ {\( Q \cdot 1_{S_T > K} \)},payoff]
      ]
      [ {Asset-or-Nothing}
        [ {Paie le prix de l'actif si \(S_T > K\)}]
        [ {\( S_T \cdot 1_{S_T > K} \)},payoff]
      ]
    ]
    [ {Compound Options}
      [ {Call on Call}
        [ {Donne le droit d'acheter\\une autre option call}]
      ]
      [ {Put on Call}
        [ {Donne le droit de vendre\\une option call}]
      ]
    ]
    [ {Chooser Options}
      [ {Permet de choisir entre un call\\ou un put à une date future}]
      [ {\( \max(S_T - K, K - S_T) \)},payoff]
    ]
    [ {Cliquet Options}
      [ {Série d’options qui se réinitialisent\\périodiquement en fonction\\des performances}]
      [ {Courantes dans les produits actions à long terme}]
    ]
    [ {Forward Start Options}
      [ {Option dont le prix d’exercice\\est déterminé à une date future \(T_1\)}]
      [ {Exemple : Option de stock pour employés}]
      [ {\( C = e^{-r(T_2 - T_1)} \cdot (S_{T_1} - K_{T_1})^+ \)},call]
    ]
    [ {Basket Options}
      [ {Options basées sur un portefeuille d’actifs}]
      [ {Le payoff peut dépendre de la moyenne,\\du minimum ou du maximum\\des prix du panier}]
      [ {Exemple : Basket \( C = e^{-rT} \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i S_i - K\right)^+ \)},call]
    ]
    [ {Ladder Options}
      [ {Verrouille les gains au fur\\et à mesure que le prix\\de l’actif atteint de\\nouveaux niveaux}]
      [ {\( \max(S_T - K_i, 0) \), où \(K_i\) sont les échelons},payoff]
    ]
    [ {Gap Options}
      [ {Le payoff dépend de deux prix d’exercice :\\\(K_1\) (strike) et \(K_2\) (trigger)}]
      [ {\( C = 1_{S_T > K_2} \cdot (S_T - K_1) \)},call]
      [ {\( P = 1_{S_T < K_2} \cdot (K_1 - S_T) \)},put]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}


Or use folders all the way down (and you will still need an excessively large piece of paper ....)

Thanks so much, @cfr! Your insights are spot-on. It’s clear the tree is too wide as-is, so I’ll take your advice and split things up into smaller sections to keep everything more readable. I'm curious on your 'folder' solution...

@JeT it's just a style provided by the edges library. it gets tricky if you want to switch between that style and non-folders. and, yes, splitting it into smaller trees is probably a good way to go, even if you then have a kind of big-overview tree to show the overall picture.
